# Composition vs inheritance for pure data structs

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct, composition

So, there are many rules to follow, such as 'composition over inheritance' one for c++.
However, this one is usually referring to interfaces. By interface here I mean '*the class that has some public methods*'.

But what about just plain data-structs?
Example:

```cpp
template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
struct some_named_data
{
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
};

struct has_those_data_as_a_member
{
    some_named_data<int, double, char> snd;
    // some more data and probably a few public methods
};

struct has_those_data_fields_inherited : public some_named_data<int, double, char>
{
    // some more data and probably a few public methods
};
```

Are there any differences in terms of design practices for such two ways, or is it just a matter of taste?

My thoughts:

1. For inheritance, it is easy to write type_traits, if I want to constrain some function with

```cpp
template<typename T>
std::is_base_of_v<some_named_data, T> // this goes somewhere
```

For composition can probably be done by c++20 concepts somehow, not sure.

2. One more name -- can be good or bad

```cpp
has_those_data_as_a_member memb;
memb.snd.a = 5; // one more name

has_those_data_fields_inherited inh;
inh.a = 5; // one less name
```

3. If inherited is a class template itself, sometimes need to write `this->a` to access members, which is annoying, but a little annoying.

So, apart from those, I don't see any particular advantages/disadvantages of one ore another.
Memory layout should be the same (I guess?).
Both here look like they model 'has a' relationship (because no private invariants, no methods).

So, are there any specific differences for this case both in terms of internal structure and design practices?

Thanks!

Comment: "Memory layout should be the same (I guess?)" Not quite. Inherting from an empty struct/class has some special rules to it. Pre-C++20, that's the only way to compose zero-sized structs without bloat.

Comment: Abstractions are still your guide. Whether you use composition or inertiance depends on the abstraction. The most likely answer will be composition since there are no member functions that would define a shared interface.

Comment: You can't slice a class made by composition; you can with inheritance.

Comment: `So, there are many rules to follow, such as 'composition over inheritance' ` not necessarily. There are many reasons to use inheritance.

Comment: Inheritance should *never* be used for convenience of implementation. It should only ever be used when there's a sensible subtyping relationship "every instance of the child *is actually* an instance of the parent" in some well-defined sense.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo well, STL implementations beg to differ. There are many cases when using inheritance without 'is-a' relationship is a good (if not only!) ways to implement desired functionality, especially in metaprogramming.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo - I have to say, the only "never" advice one should follow is "never follow other 'never' advice". Such "rules" are just the other side of cargo cults.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I'd say, it is a very definition of cargo-cult - i.e. following some other example without clear understanding what are you actually doing.